# How to not allow tagfield to change its width according to its content?

Tags: extjs6.5

I am using extjs 6.5.3 classic toolkit. I have tag field. I am allowing adding items in tag field by typing in tag field. If I type string with more characters in it tag field  is taking the width of the content. How can I avoid this?

I tried by giving width, maxWidth, shrinkWrap:false, grow: false, matchFieldWidth : false all this configs are not working.

Please help.

Thank you in advance.